# Как считывать текст в win api c++

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня есть textbox. Мне надо сделать так чтобы при вводе в него, каждый символ записывался в string. (Только мне надо на windows api (!)).

Какое событие использовать `WM_COMMAND` или `WM_CHAR` ?? или можно по другому

Comment: Совсем не ясно что именно вам нужно: чтобы вводимые символы записывались в процессе набора? Но как тогда быть с редактированием уже введенного текста?

Comment: Нет был введен текст например (Привет мир!). Нажата кнопка и весь этот текст записался в string s;

Comment: Если просто весь текст надо записать в `string s`, отправьте текстбоксу сообщение  [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: А можно поподробнее ? пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

1. > Какое событие использовать, `WM_COMMAND` или `WM_CHAR`?

   - `WM_COMMAND` используется только для нажимных элементов управления (типа кнопки) и поступает при активации этого элемента (нажатии мышью или пробелом).
   - `WM_CHAR`, в свою очередь, приходит *при нажатии любой клавиши*. Имеет смысл при необходимости раздельного получения вводимых символов, к примеру в поле ввода, прямо во время их набора.

     В то же время это событие применимо к любому элементу управления и даже окну, так как событие преобразуется из `WM_KEYDOWN` вне зависимости от класса окна.
2. > *Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509492/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-win-api-c?rq=1#comment616375_509492) автора вопроса:*
   >
   > Нет был введен текст, например, «Привет мир!». Нажата кнопка и весь этот текст записался в `string s;`.

   Это можно сделать следующим образом (для удобства восприятия использованы так называемые *message crackers* из `windowsx.h`, имеющие вид `HANDLE_MSG()`):

   ```
   #include <windowsx.h>

   static void handleCommand(HWND hWnd, int ctrlId, HWND hwndCtrl, UINT uNotifCode)
   {
       switch(ctrlId)
       {
           // ...

           case ID_КНОПКИ:
           {
               const int cchMax = Edit_GetTextLength(hwndCtrl);

               const LPTSTR lpszText = new TCHAR[cchMax];
               Edit_GetText(hwndCtrl, lpszText, cchMax);

               std::string text(lpszText, cchMax);

               // Теперь содержимое текстового поля находится в переменной text,
               // которую необходимо куда-то скопировать или переместить.

               break;
           }
   }

   // ...

   static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
       HWND   hWnd,
       UINT   uMsg,
       WPARAM wParam,
       LPARAM lParam
   )
   {
       switch(uMsg)
       {
           // ...
           HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, handleCommand);
           // ...
           default:
               return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
       }
   ```

   ---

   *Кстати, из-за возможности включения поддержки Юникода на уровне Windows API, **настоятельно рекомендую** заменить `std::string` на условно объявляемую конструкцию:*

   ```
   #if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
       typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> ui_string;
   #else
       typedef std::basic_string<char> ui_string;
   #endif
   ```

   и заменить все `std::string` на `ui_string`. В противном случае вы не сможете выполнить компиляцию с макроопределением `-DUNICODE` для перехода на Unicode вариант Windows API (то есть функции, заканчивающиеся на `W`).